# Issue with 3.8.3 bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to call a dialog from console application and here is the piece of code

```
scope.Resolve<IMessageActivity>(TypedParameter.From((IMessageActivity)activity));
DialogModule_MakeRoot.Register(scope, () => new LocationDialog());
IPostToBot postToBot = scope.Resolve<IPostToBot>();
await postToBot.PostAsync(activity, CancellationToken.None);
```

LocationDialog throws a prompt choice and while replying, i am getting this error

> String reference not set to an instance of a String

I took the code from this link [Skype For Business](https://ankitbko.github.io/2017/01/BusyBot-Sykpe-For-Business-Bot/)

Everything works fine with framework 3.3.3 and once moved to 3.8.3, it fails if my dialog throws promptchoice.

Thanks

Comment: Please add all the necessary code for us to help, like the implementation of your `LocationDialog`